# Sitecore get all Roles

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I need a list of all Roles. 
I have seen that I can get all Roles by Domain or all Roles by a User.

I thought that I could get all Domains, and then do a loop to get all Roles for each Domain.

But it seems you can get a Domain by name only, and I cant hardcode them because there will be new ones from time to time.

So, any idea how I can get all Security Roles? The names as a string would be enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use :

```
Roles.GetAllRoles()
```

from the namespace **Sitecore.Security.Accounts**

If you want to get all users from a Role you can use:

```
IEnumerable<User> _roleUsers = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.RolesInRolesManager.GetUsersInRole(Role.FromName("Your role name"), true);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking in the Sitecore.Security namespace, I forgot about System.Web.Security. I think you are talking about that one?

Comment: Sitecore.Security.Accounts is the namespace, I updated the answer

Comment: Hi, I am using Sitecore 7.2 and I cant find that Method in the Sitecore.Security.Accounts namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer isn't quite right. The GetAllRoles() method is in the RolesInRolesManager class. It can be called as follows:

```
using Sitecore.Security.Accounts;
...
IEnumerable<Role> roleList = RolesInRolesManager.GetAllRoles();
```